# How to get autopost back on a control when rendered

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have to add a dropdown control in the web part. 
I am rendering the part using HTML Strings as follows...

**StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();**

**sb.Append(div id="content); *There are quotes in the string***

**sb.Append(div class=""hb"">");**
**sb.Append(div class=""someclass"">");**
**sb.Append(h2 id=""contentpage_title"">Title");**
**sb.Append(div class=""ctn_conferences"">");****

writer.Write(sb.ToString());***

I have to add a loaded dropdown control...so I declared..

***protected DropDownList ddMyDropDown = new DropDownList();***

Then added the control in the middle of the render where I wanted as follows...

**ddMyDropDown.RenderControl(writer);**

Everything is fine....except... the post back does not work.
My event handlers are not getting executed.

When I add the control ...like  **Controls.Add(Control)** then it adds at the bottom of the part. That is not what I want.

So how do I get the post back to work?

Thanks in advance.

-Satyen

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea for the render method override but add the following:

```
protected DropDownList ddMyDropDown;

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    ddMyDropDown = new DropDownList();
    ddMyDropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
    Controls.Add(ddMyDropDown);
}
```

Also, in the render method override call EnsureChildControls() before you try and render any control setup through the CreateChildControls() method.